# PrepareForSegue not been called on IOS 6 Simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a application which is using storyboard. When I developed it, it targeted to ios 5, and everything works very well. However, when I try to run it in ios 6 simulator, I found "PrepareForSegue" method cannot be called.(In this case, my project's development target still targeted to ios 5).

This is my code for prepareForSegue below:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"sToHowManyTimesView"])
    {

        NSString *title=[relationshipStatus titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NHCThirdViewController *thirdView=[segue destinationViewController];

        thirdView.infoRequest=title;
        relationShipStatus.relstatus=title;

        NSLog(@"%@",title);

    }
    else if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SinglePage"])
    {
        NSString *title=[relationshipStatus titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
        relationShipStatus.relstatus=title;

    }
    else if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toFifthView"])
    {
        NSString *title=[relationshipStatus titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NHCFifithViewController *fifthView=[segue destinationViewController];

        fifthView.infoRequest=title;
        relationShipStatus.relstatus=title;
    }
}
```

Please help me with it.

Comment: Hrm. Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the first "if" so that you can see for sure if that method is not being called? It could be that your segue identifiers are not correct.

Comment: If it's **truly** not being called, looking at the code inside it isn't going to be much help.  Maybe describe how it's connected and triggered and whether it actually happens (visually).